# Heated body or black-body radiation color palette in R

Tags: r, colors, color-scheme

How can I define a "heated body" or "black-body radiation" color scheme for color-coding sequential data in R?

Standard R color palettes don't give an indication of ordinal, interval or ratio scaling. The `rainbow` palette is problematic for multiple reasons described by [Borland & Taylor ("Rainbow Color Map (Still) Considered Harmful", *IEEE Computer Graphics and Applications*, 2007)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4118486/). (See also [xkcd's *painbow*](https://xkcd.com/2537/).) They instead recommend using a "black-body radiation" color palette, which is elsewhere called a "heated body" palette:

[image: black-body radiation or heated body color palette]

Unfortunately, I don't seem to find an R function to create this palette. [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) and the `RColorBrewer` package are not helpful (although [this palette](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=YlOrRd&n=3) comes close), especially if I need more than 9 colors.

This question at CrossValidated is related: [Most effective use of colour in heat/contour maps](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41492/1352)

Comment: @agenis: I couldn't find an answer online, but I thought this might be interesting for other people, so I Q&A'ed, as [we are explicitly encouraged to do](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). (Plus, I have found that it's easier for *myself* to find relevant pieces of information later this way, rather than write them down somewhere and need to search for them.)

Answer (score 3):

- Take RGB values for four colors from the ["Default Color Map" page in the ParaView wiki](https://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/index.php/Default_Color_Map): (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)
- Interpolate using `grDevices::colorRamp()`

Here is a function:

```
blackBodyRadiationColors <- function(x, max_value=1) {
    # x should be between 0 (black) and 1 (white)
    # if large x come out too bright, constrain the bright end of the palette
    #     by setting max_value lower than 1
    foo <- colorRamp(c(rgb(0,0,0),rgb(1,0,0),rgb(1,1,0),rgb(1,1,1)))(x*max_value)/255
    apply(foo,1,function(bar)rgb(bar[1],bar[2],bar[3]))
}
```

And here is an example, where we indicate the years in a seasonplot of the AirPassengers data using the rainbow vs. the black-body radiation color palette:

[image: AirPassengers seasonplot]

```
library(forecast)

n.colors <- ceiling(length(AirPassengers)/frequency(AirPassengers))
colors.blackBody <- blackBodyRadiationColors(seq(0,0.6,length.out=n.colors))
colors.rainbow <- rainbow(n.colors)

opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,1),mai=c(.5,1.2,.1,.1))
    seasonplot(AirPassengers, col=colors.rainbow,
      pch=19,year.labels=TRUE,xlab="",main="",ylab="Rainbow\npalette")
    seasonplot(AirPassengers, col=colors.blackBody,ylab="Black-body\nradiation palette",
      pch=19,year.labels=TRUE,xlab="",main="",ylab="Black-body\nradiation palette")
par(opar)
```